# Change variable name in a double loop

Tags: python, variables, loops

Hello I would like to change a variable name ( the name should depend on i and j ) in a double loop, this is a simple example

```
for i in range(m) :
   for j in range(n) :
       Vector [i] = i
       d['vector_%02d' %i] = vector_i
   i=i+1
j=j+1
```

I tried d['vector_%02d' %i %j] but it doesn't work,

Regards,

Comment: What is `d` in your code?

Comment: What is `vector_i` in your code, also...

Comment: `for i in range(m)` already iterates over the numbers `0..(m - 1)` so your lines `i=i+1` and `j=j+1` are unnecessary.

Comment: @Midnighter Also the increment of `j` is completely out of place. If `m` is `0` the code would raise a `NameError`.

Answer (score 0):

According to code in your post you need to generate dictionarys key name, not variable

Anyway there's `format` function in python:

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        print 'vector_{0}_{1}'.format(i, j)
```

outs this:

```
vector_0_0
vector_0_1
vector_0_2
vector_0_3
vector_0_4
vector_1_0
....
vector_4_2
vector_4_3
vector_4_4
```

More here: docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
d['vector_%d%d' %(i,j)] = vector_i
```

Comment: Great explanation of what you are doing and formatting also.